# pouchdb live is a little too fast for realtime chat

Tags: vue.js, couchdb, vuex, pouchdb

I am using the current vuex mutation to sync to my pouch/ couchdb which is excellent. However 
As I am typing into text box I can type too fast and this can mean letters are not sent to sync, which is annoying but not a killer however if I edit in the middle and type at speed sometimes cursor will jump to the end, I want live as its live text but I would like to poll a little slower does anyone have any suggests.... there was a suggestion of using since : 'now'  but that doesnt seem to slow it down

```
    syncDB: () => {
  pouchdb.replicate.from(remote).on('complete', function () {
    store.commit('GET_ALL_NODES')
    store.commit('GET_MY_NODES')
    store.commit('GET_POSITIONS')
    store.commit('GET_CONNECTIONS')
    store.commit('GET_EMOJI')
    // turn on two-way, continuous, retriable sync
    pouchdb
      .sync(remote, {
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        attachments: true,
      })
      .on('change', function () {
        // pop info into function to find out more
        store.commit('GET_ALL_NODES')
        store.commit('GET_MY_NODES')
        store.commit('GET_POSITIONS')
        store.commit('GET_CONNECTIONS')
        store.commit('GET_EMOJI')
      })
      .on('paused', function () {
        // replication paused (e.g. replication up to date, user went offline)
        // console.log('replication paused')
      })
      .on('active', function () {
        // replicate resumed (e.g. new changes replicating, user went back online)
        //console.log('back active')
      })
      .on('denied', function () {
        // a document failed to replicate (e.g. due to permissions)
      })
      .on('complete', function () {
        // handle complete
      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
  })
},
```

Comment: I think this is not a problem with PouchDB itself but in Vue component. What v-on listener do you use? If you happen to use `@input` switch to `@change`, or `@keydown.enter.prevent` or `@blur` so the event will emit after you done typing not in the middle of typing.

Answer (score 0):

I added a debounce via lodash to the text input which helps a lot it’s not perfect especially if you are editing in the middle of text but less jumps to the end and general start speedier typing isn’t an issue